# How to run SQL connection within variable with second SQL query

Tags: linux, bash, psql

Apologies if the title is unclear, I am not sure how to explain it.

I have the following variable made, which is basically one that I can put in a script and use to run SQL queries from within the terminal where needed:

```
use_sql= psql -U TravelOwner -d TravelDB -c
```

An example of how I would use this variable is as follows:

```
$use_sql 'SELECT * FROM country'
```

This makes it that I don't have to keep writing the full psql command everytime.
The desired result is that it should run is if it says, this query runs fine from the terminal:

```
psql -U TravelOwner -d TravelDB -c 'SELECT * FROM country'
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: Other than the missing quotes here `use_sql="psql -U TravelOwner -d TravelDB -c"`, I don't think there will be any errors/issues. Else could you please rephrase what issues/errors are you getting when you are trying to run it ??

Comment: You might look into using a `.pgpass` file per the postgres documentation: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/libpq-pgpass.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most logical way to prevent repeating stuffs in any programming languages, is by using functions or named procedures:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash

db_query()
{
  psql -U TravelOwner -d TravelDB -c "$1"
}

# Then use the function to perform various queries
db_query 'SELECT * FROM country;'
```